# AngularJS Button to reload state does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-click

I want to have a button on the front end (AngularJS) that refreshes the changes made to the database. I have tried the following in the html:

```
<button ng-click="reloadState" data-translate> Refresh Database </button>
```

In the app.js file, I have this function in my controller:

```
$scope.reloadState = function() {
   $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
}
```

I have also tried:

```
$scope.reloadState = function() {
    $state.reload();
};
```

and:

```
$scope.reloadState = function() {
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Why does nothing happen when I click the button? Ps. I am using ui-router.

Comment: Rather than refreshing the page and reloading resources, why don't you fetch new data with `$http`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is traditional Javascript by using location.reload();

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try $state.transitionTo($state.current, {}, {reload: true})

Comment: So in my controller, I have                                                       $scope.reloadState = function() {
    $state.transitionTo($state.current, {}, {
     reload: true
 });
  }

Comment: looks like there's also a $state.reload method

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_reload