# AngularJS reload page function and automatic log out conflict each other

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, reload

I am writing an app that uses `AngularJS` and `ui-router.` I have a button that refreshes the page by reloading the page, and the functionality that automatically logs users out when the window or tab is closed. Now both functions work awesome (and done using traditional javascript to make things simple). See below:

```
<script>
      // Refreshes by reloading page
      function refresh() {
          location.reload();
      }

      // Automatically logs users out when browser or tab is closed
      window.onunload = function(){
          localStorage.clear();
      }
</script>
```

However, the problem is when the reload button is clicked it also logs the current user out and this is not what I want. I only want the user to be logged out when the window is closed. Is there anyway this can be done? Will reloading the route in my controller fix the problem?

Comment: are you creating a SPA app (single page application) ?

Comment: I am creating an app that has multiple pages (with nav bar) but all the pages are written in one file- index.ejs @Hardy

Comment: its better to refresh particular page controller instead location.reload() because it will reload your entire app and redirect to the first default page that you have defined into your ui-router.

Comment: How exactly do I refresh particular controllers? I have tried everything here @Hardy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31363435/angularjs-button-to-reload-state-does-not-work/31363716?noredirect=1#comment50766495_31363716

Answer (score -1):

Not a good solution but you can use a global flag that you can set when you are reloading the page

```
var refh = false;
function refresh(){
  ref = true;
  location.reload()
}

window.unonload = function(){
  if(!refh)
   localStorage.clear();
}
```

Comment: Why is this voted down, this solution works! @geeky_sh

Comment: Nvm this won't work when you close a seperate tab and then refresh the database @geeky_sh